# Как переместить метку на картах?

Tags: google-maps-api, yandex-maps-api

Какие функции есть для GoogleMap и какие для YandexMap для того, чтобы изменить расположение текущей метки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По этой теме очень много информации. Если просто `html`, `php` - смотри [ТУТ](http://habrahabr.ru/post/110460/) и [ЗДЕСЬ](http://habrahabr.ru/post/145152/) Там описываются работа с `google maps api` - стандартными скриптами и с библиотекой `js`. А если `CMS`, то используй соответствующие плагины.
На тему с яндексом есть официальный [МАНУАЛ](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/1.x/dg/tasks/how-to-add-placemark.xml)